# How to add the current date into a redirect command in Linux?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I am currently redirecting the output of a program to a file as follows

```
 python checkTemps.py >> test.txt
```

This appends a new line of CSV data to test.txt each time it is run

```
71.2, 74.1, 63.8, 69.2, 74.64, 73.85, 76.08
```

I would like to insert the current date/time followed by a comma at the beginning of each line to look as follows

```
2023-08-30_20:45, 71.2, 74.1, 63.8, 69.2, 74.64, 73.85, 76.08
```

I can't figure out how to execute the echo command and append the comma and run the python app in a single line. Here is one of many variations I've tried

```
echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M), python checkTemps.py >> test.txt
```

Comment: Another option is to use `ts` from moreutils: `python checkTemps.py | ts '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M, ' >> test.txt`. Is also works for multiline output.

Comment: Worth of a nod for actually providing a MCRE (or MRE) with your attempt to solve the problem. These have been in short-supply lately.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to do this yourself, there's actually a `ts` (timestamp) program you can use as a filter to automatically add timestamps.

The default format is usable but you can also specify a format compatible with `strftime`, such as the following including seconds to make it clear that it's working (your desired format should be `"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M,"):

```bash
pax$ ( for i in {1..5}; do sleep ${i}; echo line ${i}; done ) | ts "%H:%M:%S"
11:21:18 start
11:21:19 line 1
11:21:21 line 2
11:21:24 line 3
11:21:28 line 4
11:21:33 line 5
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can just take "normal" output and pipe the whole thing unchanged through `ts`, rather than changing every single output statement.

I've even written scripts that automatically do time stamping without intervention:

```bash
pax$ cat prog.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is the magic here.
if [[ "${TS_ACTIVE}" -ne 1 ]]; then TS_ACTIVE=1 "$0" "$@" | ts "%H:%M:%S"; exit; fi

echo start "$@"
for i in {1..5}; do
    sleep ${i}
    echo line ${i}
done

pax$ ./prog.sh abc d ef
11:41:30 start abc d ef
11:41:31 line 1
11:41:33 line 2
11:41:36 line 3
11:41:40 line 4
11:41:45 line 5
```

Comment: Image that, a short, concise Linux utility written to solve that particular problem `:)` I admit having reinvented the wheel in C before discovering `ts` - and that was many years into Linux use...

Comment: David C. Rankin as I move to Linux after a 30+ year career with MS and Windows I see WAY to many wheels with Linux.